# How to make fixed sidebar stop at footer?

Tags: jquery, fixed, sidebar

Right now I´m using this code for my conditionally fixed sidebar:

```
$(function() {
 var a = function() {
 var b = $(window).scrollTop();
 var d = $("#sidebar-right").offset().top;
 var c=$("#scroller");
 var e=$("#scroller-left");
 if (b>d) {
  c.css({position:"fixed",top:"5px"})
  e.css({position:"fixed",top:"5px"})
 } else {
  if (b<=d) {
    c.css({position:"relative",top:""})
    e.css({position:"relative",top:""})
  }
 }
};
$(window).scroll(a);a()
});
```

The problem is: If the sidebar content is too high, it goes over the footer. What do I have to add to the code, that it stops at the footer?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the page to always be high enough to fit the sidebar in, or do you want to cut the sidebar off so that it always fits?

For the former, just make an element that is part of the document flow (such as perhaps #sidebar-right in your example) larger than then scroller;

```
if ($("#sidebar-right").height() < $("#scroller").height())
    $("#sidebar-right").height($("#scroller").height());
```

If it is the latter, then cut off the sidebar, and hide any overflow;

```
if ($("#scroller").height() > ($("#footer").offset().top - $("#sidebar-right").offset().top)) {
    $("#scroller").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("#scroller").height($("#footer").offset().top - $("#sidebar-right").offset().top));
}
```

Comment: Hi matt, I´d like to have it the second way. But I have a question: Is it cut off at the top or at the bottom? I tried to implement the code but I do not know where to put it. Everywhere I put it, it made the whole sidebar not fixed anymore. Thanks for your fast help!! lena

Comment: For your further information: The #scroller is just a little div around the content of the sidebar. I dont know if it´s even needed, but it worked for me and I was happy, not having to change anything :)

Comment: My code was only a sample.  For it to work, you will at least need a footer element with `id="footer"`.  Aside from that, you could call it within $(function() { ));

Comment: I have an element with id="footer", but if I put it where you say, the sidebare stays where it is and does not follow when scrolling down :( do you have an opinion why? thanks, lena

Comment: and in your first it´s: ("#sidebar-right").height() < $("#scroller").height()  but my sidebar and the scroller height is just the same, as the #scroller is just a div around the content of the sidebar.